# ASP.NET MVC "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 0." when trying to get data from the table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
namespace PayrollSystem.Models
{
    public class FormAddEmployee
    {
        public string FirstName { set; get; }
        public string LastName { set; get; }
        public decimal PayRate { set; get; }
        public DateTime StartDate { set; get; }
        public DateTime EndDate { set; get; }

        private string m_connectionString;

        public void Connect(string server, string database)
        {
            m_connectionString = string.Format("Data Source ='{0}'; Initial Catalog = {1}; Integrated Security=SSPI", server, database);
        }

        public void SaveEmployee()
        {
            var commandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO Personnel (FirstName, LastName, PayRate, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', {2}, '{3}', '{4}')", FirstName, LastName, PayRate, StartDate, EndDate);

            SQLDataWriter(commandText);
        }



        public void GetEmployeeByLastName(string lastName)
        {
            var commandText = string.Format("SELECT FirstName, LastName, PayRate, StartDate, EndDate FROM Personnel WHERE LastName = '{0}'", LastName);

            var retValue = SQLDataReader(commandText);
            var rec = retValue.Rows[0];
            FirstName = rec.ItemArray[0].ToString();
            LastName = rec.ItemArray[1].ToString();
            PayRate = Convert.ToDecimal(rec.ItemArray[2].ToString());
            StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rec.ItemArray[3].ToString());
            EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rec.ItemArray[4].ToString());

        }

        public DataTable SQLDataReader(string sqlCmd)
        {
            var dataTable = new DataTable();
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(m_connectionString))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd, con) { CommandTimeout = 500 })
                {
                    var sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    sqlAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                }
            }

            return dataTable;

        }

        public void SQLDataWriter(string sqlCmd)
        {
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(m_connectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                try
                {
                    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd, con))
                    {
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
            }
        }



    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query probably doesn't return any data. Might be better to check before accessing it.

```
var retValue = SQLDataReader(commandText);

if(retValue.Rows.Count > 0) 
{
            var rec = retValue.Rows[0];
            FirstName = rec.ItemArray[0].ToString();
            LastName = rec.ItemArray[1].ToString();
            PayRate = Convert.ToDecimal(rec.ItemArray[2].ToString());
            StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rec.ItemArray[3].ToString());
            EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rec.ItemArray[4].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solved my problem. I was passing wrong parameter in my SQL query. That's why it was returning zero results.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should be using parameterized commands to protect yourself from sql injection... In this instance you are indexing into the Rows collection without checking if there are any values in Rows.

Do this instead:

```
if(retValue.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    var rec = retValue.Rows[0];
}
```